# How to split a Dataset from a .csv file for Training and Testing in java?

Tags: java, csv

I'm using java to split a .csv file into training and testing set. I've researched but didn't find any easy and flexible way to do this,there were plenty of code in python but in java didn't find any. Is there any method to do this where it's easily understandable the code

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Are you asking about how to read a csv file in Java?

Comment: Is it allowed to use some libraries or you have to build your custom solution? If so, then look at opencsv lib.

Comment: Thank you for reply, yes library code would be very helpful. it would help me to understand if there is any code snippet of opencsv splitting csv file into training and testing data set to 80%-20%

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String fileName= "Archivos/Students.csv"; //Depends on your file location
        BufferedReader  inputStream =  null;
        try{
            inputStream= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));//se abre el Stream de lectura
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("Reading "+fileName);
            while((line=inputStream.readLine()) != null){

                String[] dataLine = line.split(",");
                for (int i=0;i<dataLine.length;i++){
                    System.out.println(line); //Reads each line from the csv File
                    System.out.println("Name: "+dataLine[0]);
                    System.out.println("Last Name: "+ dataLine[1]);
                    System.out.println("ID: "+dataLine[2]);
                    System.out.println("State of residence: "+ dataLine[3]);
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }

        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Data "+ fileName +" not found");
        } catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Error while reading " + fileName);
        }finally{
            //Close the Stream into a try-catch because it can throw an IOException
            try{
                inputStream.close();
            } catch(IOException ex){
                Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            }
        }

    }
```

[This is what my csvFile contains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Gcd.png)

Basically just apply ".split(",")" to the line you're reading from the csv File (line 10 in code).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wan to split the csv file into training and testing data set 80% to 20% .I wonder if there is any library code for it